# How to take backup database from server to client PC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want to take database backup from server PC to client PC. I can save it into server PC, but I can't save it into client PC.

I'm using ASP.NET and C#. Here is my DB backup code:

```
string Msg = null;
string FileName = "E:\\DBName.Bak"; // directory where file will be save.
```

SQL code:

```
BACKUP DATABASE  standard  TO DISK = '" + FileName + "' WITH FORMAT")"
```

Comment: @Rashed Your question refers to some "db backup code". Either I am overlooking something or something is missing. Also, it may help if you could indicate which database server product you are using or if you target multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better option would be to copy the database data into an xml file then download that. This circumvents most of the security issues with messing about with SQL folder permissions that should really be left untouched.

Theres an article on my website with sample code on how to create a [database backup and restore facility via an asp.net web page](http://www.mykeblack.com/scripts/asp.net/database/asp-net-backup-restore-database) which dumps the data into xml files for you to download, and there is also a restore facility so you can upload your xml files again to restore data. You can have another copy of the restore facility on your local machine if you need to restore the database locally.

Answer (score 4):

Is this possible?  Yes, in the strictest sense of possible.

What needs to happen, is that the drive where you make the backup, must be available to both the SQL Server and IIS (i.e. they both need read permissions & SQL also needs write permissions).  Then, you can generate the .BAK file, and download it via a hyperlink.

That said, there's a distinct reason why this is a serious pain to accomplish, as it's extremely bad from a security POV.

Comment: at first i will check the db username,pass. After that a valid user can take this backup.

Comment: Why on earth would I have code to do this?   While yes, I do have code to read a network share and serve files from it, that's only half the battle, as the permissions settings for the IIS user account on the web server also factors greatly into this. Additionally, I indicated that I thought it a bad idea; I don't code what I view as bad ideas.